# How to Inherit C++/CLI Interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, assemblies, c++-cli

I have declared an interface in C++/CLI and made it an assembly(DLL). I want that interface to be implement by a C# app. I have added the reference but my C# assembly does not detecting my C++/CLI interface and says "Could not find: You are missing some assembly refernce."

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your dll support CLR. (Tab General in Configuration Properties in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Knowing this is an old question, but I had the same issue.
Additionally, your c++/cli needs to provide some source (cpp) code (which is actually nearly empty):

IXYprovider.h:

`namespace Interfaces
 {
      public interface class IXYprovider
      {
        ...
      }
}`

IXYProvider.cpp:

`#include "IXYprovider.h"
namespace Interfaces
{
}`

That makes it visible to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `interface class` is declared `public` in the C++/CLI assembly.  I recommend the free version of Red Gate .NET Reflector for viewing visibility of types in a compiled assembly.

Comment: yes everything declared public in C++/CLI assembly. as this is an interfaceso i just declared public class interface and not wrapped inside it in any namespace. I wrapped after but still not recognizing namespace and interfaces declared inside. I used this interface in C++/CLI assembly successfully butnot working in C#

Comment: .NET Reflector not showing C++/CLI assembly(in which interface declared) as reference. but C++/CLI assembly(which one implementing interface as well) properly showing assembly as reference. Strange behaviour in .NET framework.

Comment: Did you use the `interface class` keyword when declaring the interface?  C# can only see managed types, while C++/CLI can see and use both managed and native types.

Answer (score 0):

Is the interface defined within a namespace within the C++/CLI assembly?  If so have you put 'using [namespace]' at the top of your C# file?

Comment: it says same error : "Are you missing some assembly reference...."
By defining interface in namespace, adding using [namespace] and including .dll as reference assembly , still its unable to see that interface.